# How do i fix this PHP CODE

Tags: php, geturl

It says theres an error

I'm trying to make it grab between *playlist.m3u8?wmsAuthSign=* and *"* on what ever page I put after *mylink.com/file.php?f=whatever* then the *whatever* would then be placed after the *www.linkhere.com/* in the GETURL code so it grabs between *playlist.m3u8?wmsAuthSign=* and *"* on the *linkhere.com/whatever* page ( if that makes sense

Here is the code:

```
<?php
    function getURL($u){
        $u = file_get_contents("http://{$u}");
        return $u != false ? $u : "";
    }
    function GetStringBetween($string, $start, $finish){
        $string = " ".$string;
        $position = strpos($string, $start);
        if ($position == 0) return "";
        $position += strlen($start);
        $length = strpos($string, $finish, $position) - $position;
        return substr($string, $position, $length);
    }
    $stream = GetStringBetween(getURL("www.linkhere.com/<?=!isset($_GET["f"]) ? "filehere.php" : htmlspecialchars($_GET["f"])?>"),"playlist.m3u8?wmsAuthSign=", '"');
?>
```

Comment: *"it says theres an error"*, what's the error?

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"', expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in /home/ygwtljbj/public_html/fs2.php on line 22 and line 22 is the  $stream line

Comment: There aren't even 22 lines in the code sample you've provided, so that error is either from something else, or you haven't shown us your actual code.

Comment: line 22 is the  $stream line in the code

Comment: You can't use double quotes inside double quotes, you need to escape them or use single quotes, the string inside `getURL` is giving your syntax error.

Comment: You tried to add php code into php code: <?php ... <?

Comment: so i need to make all the " into '?

Comment: i cant add a php into a php like that? im sooo confused lol

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
    function getURL($u){
        $u = file_get_contents("http://{$u}");
        return $u != false ? $u : "";
    }
    function GetStringBetween($string, $start, $finish){
        $string = " ".$string;
        $position = strpos($string, $start);
        if ($position == 0) return "";
        $position += strlen($start);
        $length = strpos($string, $finish, $position) - $position;
        return substr($string, $position, $length);
    }


$url = (!isset($_GET["f"])) ? "filehere.php" : htmlspecialchars($_GET["f"]);
$stream = GetStringBetween(getURL("www.linkhere.com/".$url),"playlist.m3u8?wmsAuthSign=", '"');
?>
```

so like this?

Comment: That should be it....

Answer (score 0):

```
$url = (!isset($_GET["f"])) ? "filehere.php" : htmlspecialchars($_GET["f"]);
$stream = GetStringBetween(getURL("www.linkhere.com/".$url),"playlist.m3u8?wmsAuthSign=", '"');
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"),"' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING) in /home/ygwtljbj/public_html/fs2.php on line 24 which is the $stream

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this".

Answer (score 0):

Don't you think that that it makes much sense to break your codes down in steps & sequences until you can program while sleeping? Besides, breaking your code down into steps helps you see things clearer and learn as well. As one advances, one finds himself even writing a complex algorithm (that would require 30 lines for the apprentice) in one single line... but until then... the apprentice is advised to start from the building blocks, then build up and even do it the complex way (so long as the simple, long, boring way has worked and yield much insight)....

```
    <?php
        function getURL($u){
            $u        = file_get_contents("http://{$u}");
            return ($u  != false) ? $u : "";
        }

        function GetStringBetween($string, $start, $finish){
            $string      = " ".$string;
            $position    = strpos($string, $start);

            if ($position == 0){ return "";}

            $position  += strlen($start);
            $length     = strpos($string, $finish, $position) - $position;

            return substr($string, $position, $length);
        }

        $f      = ( !isset($_GET["f"]) ) ? "filehere.php" : htmlspecialchars(trim($_GET["f"]);
        $url        = "www.linkhere.com/{$f}";
        $theURI = getURL($url); 

        $stream    = GetStringBetween($theURI,'playlist.m3u8?wmsAuthSign=', '\"');
    ?>
```